# Saving SPFile to local hard disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to retrieve the file from sharepoint to local hard disk.

Here is my code:

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile("http://localhost/Basics.pptx");                
byte[] data = file.OpenBinary();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\krg\Desktop\xyz.pptx",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);

BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);            
w.Write(data, 0, (int)file.Length);            
w.Close();            
fs.Close();
```

When I am trying to open that file, it is showing as a corrupted file.

> The original file size is 186kb, after download the file size is 191kb.

What is the solution to download the file from sharepoint..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the BinaryWriter:

```
int size = 10 * 1024;
using (Stream stream = file.OpenBinaryStream())
{
  using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\krg\Desktop\xyz.pptx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    int bytesRead;
    while((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
      fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the file is not an even multiple of 10 * 1024, the last call to fs.Write will write garbage characters at the end of the file. Also, the file size of the written file will always be a multiple of 10 * 1024. See Igauthier's corrected version.

Answer (score 14):

Just a little contribution to this answer. It's better to  check the number of bytes read in each bloc so that the stream written will be the exact replicat of the stream read from SharePoint. 
See correction below.

```
int size = 10 * 1024;
using (Stream stream = file.OpenBinaryStream())
{  
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\krg\Desktop\xyz.pptx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
 {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
   int nbBytesRead =0;
   while((nbBytesRead=stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
   {
      fs.Write(buffer, 0, nBytesRead);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't contribute an edit unless it more than 6 chars. But there is a typo in this answer `nBytesRead` should be `nbBytesRead`